# Typescript - jQuery each index is string

Tags: jquery, typescript, types, casting

For some reason, Typescript is reporting `index` in the following jQuery loop as a string.

```
$.each(locations, (index, marker) => {

    if(this.options && this.options.bounds_marker_limit) {
        if(index <= (this.options.bounds_marker_limit - 1)) this.bounds.extend(position);
    } else {
        this.bounds.extend(position);
    }
});
```

Typescript is reporting

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.

for the line

`if(index <= (this.options.bounds_marker_limit - 1)) this.bounds.extend(position);`.

If I try `(index as number)` then it reports

> Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'number'

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: What elements does "locations" array contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `parseInt()`:

```
if(parseInt(index) <= (this.options.bounds_marker_limit - 1))
```

Or like this:

```
locations.each((index: number, elem: Element): void => {
   // index is a number
})
```

according to jQuery typescript declation file:

```
each(func: (index: number, elem: Element) => any): JQuery;
```

Comment: Setting `(index: number)` worked, I didn't even realise you could set the type of properties which are returned by other functions!